# Prevent repeated GET within loop when using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, settimeout

I am trying to run a javascript that would set background color of a page as red, wait  seconds and then get a value from a webpage and then turn green and then stay green for that many seconds before becoming red again and repeating indefinitely.

Am using JQuery GET to get the webpage.

My code

```
<script>
        function g() {
            document.body.bgColor = 'green';
        }
function r() {
            document.body.bgColor = 'red';
        }


 $(document).ready(function(){

     while(1)
     {
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/t.html", function( data ){
        setTimeout'g()',10000);

        setTimeout('r()',data*1000);

        });



     }

 });
    </script>
```

**Problem :** Somehow the seTimeout is causing the loop to continue. By the time the page waits a few seconds hundreds of GET requests are generated.  I need the full process to freeze while the code is waiting the given time. 
My browser is detecting this continuous loop due to heavy activity and asking to kill it.

Please help me sort this out.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that. You need recursion instead.

Comment: Why are you using `while(1)`

Comment: Need to keep doing this till page is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
  r();
});
function r(){    
    var timeOut = 5000;
    if(document.body.bgColor=='green'){
         document.body.bgColor = 'red';
           timeOut = 10000;
    }else{
        document.body.bgColor = 'green';        
    }    
    setTimeout(r,timeOut);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Hnuy8/

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout will not freeze your while function, because its async. It will just wait and execute `g()` after the given time.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/t.html", function( data ){
     if(data=="green") g(); 
     else r();
    });
},10000);
```

this would execute the GET-Request every 10 seconds and set the background to green, when `data` is green, otherwise to red.

I'm not completly understanding what you want to achieve, so you would need to modify this a bit.

Comment: data contains a value, the green need to stay that many seconds

Comment: and when do you want to trigger your get-request again? because if you want to trigger it right after the background goes red, then you will see the red one only during request + your 10000 secounds you want to wait for `g()` (should be a total of 10100ms), is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

please have a look

```
 <script>
            function g() {
                document.body.bgColor = 'green';
            }
            function r() {
                document.body.bgColor = 'red';
            }


     $(document).ready(function(){

        function changeBG()
        {
         $.get("http://localhost:8080/t.html", function( data )
         {
               setTimeout('g()',10000);
               setTimeout('r()',data*1000);
               changeBG();
         });

        }
     changeBG();
     });

     </script>
```